# $_SERVER in Aptana don't show elements

Tags: php, global-variables, aptana, dreamweaver, superglobals

In DreamWeaver when we type $_SERVER, dreamweaver will open a dropdown menu to select an element, but in Aptana we don't have this option, is there any way to add this option to Aptana?

Comment: I would ask that in the aptana mailinglist or similar. It might be that this is a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue with aptana development at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2898 that refers to this specific issue.  So I guess this feature is still on their to do list.

You can do more generalised command assist by doing the following for a local project

1. Click “Project” tab (found on the left panel of Aptana environment).
2. Create a new project (right click, New -> Project…).
3. (on New Project window, under Aptana Projects) Select “PHP Project“.
4. Click “Next” button, type in your project name then click “Finish” button.
5. Select and right click on the newly created project and click on “Properties“.
6. Select “Project Natures“.
7. Tick “com.aptana.ide.editor.php.phpnature (PHP Nature)“.
8. Then click “Ok” button.

more detailed instructions at http://ryan.rawswift.com/2009/05/17/aptana-how-to-enable-php-code-assist/

Comment: Thanks, my project is PHP now and other assist is enable for me, I found command>PHP>Edit this bundle and when I click on this Aptana will create a new project with PHP Assists codes, is it possible to change this codes ? How can I change?